# Can we send email without opening default gmail app

Tags: android

**I tried  to send email with gmail send and *JSSEProvider*, but this is asking for password also to send an email. Can we send emails in any other way without opening default gmail app?**

Comment: _but this requires password_ The account password ? This seems fair to me. I had to open the mail app the last time I had to send a mail from my app, mostly to have the validation of the user.

Comment: Yes, account password.I want to send a report on button click .But i have only sender email id and receiver email id.I want to send email without opening gmail default app

Comment: Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, write your own mail sender... there is example on internet already so I will not answer here ;)

Comment: OK ,Will try .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to create a web-service which send Email to particular Email-id.And you have to call that web service from your app.